# ¿Cómo puedo hacerle una suma a una variable en php?

Tags: php

quería saber cómo puedo obtener una variable, y cuando obtenga esa variable, por ejemplo que se sumen 6 números más. Por ejemplo en en mi código

```
echo '<p data-purecounter-start="0" 
data-purecounter-end="'.$row.'" 
data-purecounter-duration="1" 
class="counter purecounter"></p>';
```

en este código estoy llamando el resultado de lo que me dio el resultado de cuantas cuentas hay creadas en la base de datos, una vez obtenido eso quiero que al obtener eso se le sumen 2 valores más, por ejemplo, tengo 230 cuentas, pero al sumar aparezca que hay 232. Es un juego de sumas.

Comment: Pues, falta codigo para entender que tratas de hacer... sumarle 6 a una variable es facil.

Comment: A ver, nosé si me explique correctamente, quiero sumarle 6 a una variable, ¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: $variable + 6 ... ahora, no se que variable, no se como quieres que se vea, o en que momento hacerlo... nisiquiera se que tipo es la variable.

Comment: ¿A qué variable hay que sumarle valores y en qué contexto? Parecería que trabajas con atributos `data-` de Javascript y quizá convenga que la suma ocurra del lado del cliente (usando Javascript). Por favor aclara tu pregunta.

Comment: `<?php
                
$query = "SELECT factionID FROM factions ORDER BY factionID";  
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
echo '<p data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="'.$row. + 2'" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="counter purecounter"></p>';

?>` este es el código al obtener la variable, el data- es para un efecto y darle diseño a la página, lo que importa es donde está data-purecounter-end es para cuando termine el contador y quede como un texto, pero intente hacer lo que me dijo excorpion y tengo el siguiente error....

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ''" data-purecounter-duration="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\index.php on line 252`

Comment: en la línea de "echo"

Comment: Haz la suma fuera de la cadena, por ejemplo: `$suma=$row+2;` y luego usas `$suma`  de este modo: `echo '<p data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="'.$suma.'" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="counter purecounter"></p>';`

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias me sirvió ;)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer la suma fuera de la cadena, por ejemplo:

```
$suma=$row+2;
```

Y luego usar `$suma` en la cadena:

```
echo '<p data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="'.$suma.'" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="counter purecounter"></p>';
```

O, puedes usar [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php), encerrando todo dentro de comillas dobles. Así el código queda más claro que usando concatenaciones, lo único es que debes escapar con `\` las comillas internas.

```
printf("<p data-purecounter-start=\"0\" data-purecounter-end=\"%d\" data-purecounter-duration=\"1\" class=\"counter purecounter\"></p>",$row+2);
```

Aquí el marcador `%d` será reemplazado por el resultado de la suma de `$row+2`.